# Testing yeoman generator locally

Tags: generator, yeoman

I'm creating a yeoman generator for my web projects.

But I wonder how I can try and test my changes before publishing it?

Since I have installed it once, it will not run my local development version, instead it runs my installed version.

Any suggestions on how can test-run my local development version?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I finally found some information on how to accomplish this:

if you wish to develop on the generators code base, and debug locally, a common way to do so is to rely on npm link

1. git clone the generators repo locally
2. cd into that repository and run `npm link`. It'll install required dependencies and install the package globally, using a symbolic link to your local version.
3. If you want to install sub generators, you need to do so in the context of a yeoman-generator package linked earlier. Cd into the sub generators package you have cloned locally and run `npm link`.
4. We now have everything linked and known on the system, we now need to link the sub-generator repo into the parent one, yeoman-generator cloned and linked in step 1 & 2.

https://github.com/yeoman/generator/wiki/Testing-generators

**EDIT:**

Updated link for info: https://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html

Comment: The latest docs for this are at: http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html (under _"Running the generator"_)

Comment: Is there no way to test the generator without installing it globally?  I would like to test my generator without affecting the global npm installation.

Comment: @tttppp You can run a generator from a path using `yo /path/to/generator/module`. That path would be the path to the generator module itself.

Comment: I send you so much love <3

Answer (score 4):

If by "running locally" you mean the ability to test your generator and its flow you can simply do this.

1. In your project directory folder run `npm link`. If this passes in flying colors, go to step 2.
2. Open a terminal and cd into the folder you wish to initiate a project.
3. Run `yo generator-theNameOfYourGenerator`. This will run your generator.