# How to create and launch a local yeoman generator

Tags: generator, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I want to create a local generator for personal use only, i have installed yeoman and run the `yo generator` command :

[image: yeoman generator question]

As shown in the picture it says the name is already exists on npm i am wondering how can i create and launch locally a yeoman generator ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey you can take a look at these links. I think you will get what you are looking for here.

1) [Steps to setup yeoman locally](http://yeoman.io/codelab/setup.html)

2) [How to test-run the local development version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037761/testing-yeoman-generator-locally)

3) [GitHub-Running the generator locally](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-gulp-webapp/issues/223)